# How to create broken lines on CSS/HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to create the broken line using HTML/CSS/JS, not picture.
It has to look like in a photo.

[image]

P.S. sorry for my ENG)

Comment: What do you mean by broken line?

Comment: I would call it "line with an angle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.broken-line {
  width: 180px; /* The width/length of the normal line */
  height: 10px; /* The "height" of the broken part */
  border-top: 2px solid #19c4b0; /* The normal line */
  border-left: 2px solid #19c4b0; /* The broken line */

  transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```
<div class="broken-line"></div>
```

You could also add a border-radius easily if you want...
Example:

```
...
border-radius: 10px;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.broken-line {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.broken-line:before {
    position: absolute; left: -1px; top: -1px;
    content: '';
    border-top: 10px solid #000;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.broken-line:after {
    position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -2px;
    content: '';
    border-top: 10px solid white;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="broken-line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an SVG to make something like this pretty easily.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 80" width="500" height="80" stroke="blue">
  <text x="75" y="22" fontsize="20" stroke="black">I'm text and I'm on a line lalalalala</text>
  <line x1="0" x2="50" y1="80" y2="30" />
  <line x1="50" x2="500" y1="30" y2="30" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
.broken-line {
 border-top: 5px solid red;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
```

You can change the border-radius to whatever you want to make it more sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's multiple ways to accomplish it with html/css/svg/js. Here's an example of one technique to get you started.

```css
body {
  padding: 5rem 2rem;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.line-tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.75rem;
  border-bottom: dodgerblue 2px solid;
  transform: translateY(-2rem);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.line-tooltip:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.1rem;
  left: -.5rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#line-test {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

#line-test:hover + .line-tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <i id="line-test" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> &lt;- Hover the icon...
  <aside class="line-tooltip">Hey I'm some text that makes a nifty tooltip. Yay!</aside>
</div>
```